# Use of 'sudo' for part of a Python script

Tags: python, sudo

I have a program that automatically calls the following script.

The script works up to point x, but it needs root privileges to perform the code from this point on. Can I give the script sudo privileges for the last 14 lines of this script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib
import time
import subprocess
import fcntl, sys
import shutil
import os

################################################### locking section
pid_file = '/run/lock/LOCKFILE-FOR-THIS-SCRIPT.pid'
fh = open(pid_file, 'w')
try:
    fcntl.lockf(fh, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
    # another instance is running
    print 'Error: Another instance is running...'
    sys.exit(0)
################################################## locking section end



from email.mime.text import MIMEText

USERNAME = "hhhh"
PASSWORD = "hhhh"
MAILTO  = "hhhhhh"

msg = MIMEText('hhhhhhhhh')
msg['Subject'] = 'from pi motion script'
msg['From'] = USERNAME
msg['To'] = MAILTO

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
server.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(USERNAME, MAILTO, msg.as_string())
server.quit()

subprocess.call("cp -avfu /mnt/*.jpg /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

time.sleep(10)

subprocess.call("cp -avfu /mnt/*.jpg /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

time.sleep(10)

subprocess.call("cp -avfu /mnt/*.jpg /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

time.sleep(10)

subprocess.call("cp -avfu /mnt/*.jpg /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

time.sleep(180)

subprocess.call("mv /mnt/*.jpg /home/pi/box/pi_pictures", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

time.sleep(180)

#---------------------------------------------
#----Sudo from here on-words--------Point x---
#---------------------------------------------



dir = "/home/pi/box/pi_pictures" #dir where files are to be sorted
#dir = sys.argv[1]
os.chdir(dir)
for f in os.listdir(dir):

    if f.endswith(".jpg"):

        ftime = time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(f))

        ctime_dir = str(ftime.tm_year) + \
                    '-' + str(ftime.tm_mon) + \
                    '-' + str(ftime.tm_mday)

        if not os.path.isdir(ctime_dir):
            os.mkdir(ctime_dir)

        dst = ctime_dir + '/' + f\

        shutil.move(f,dst)
        # print("File " + f +" has been moved to " + dst)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The script would have to start off with the privileges needed to manipulate the directories/files.

Can't you change the ownership of the directories/files so that the script owner already has the needed privileges?

This isn't a Raspberry Pi question.

Comment: Thought it may be possible, sorry it is a python question, running on my PI.